# multi step form with React , Formik and Material UI, issue with checkboxes and autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, formik, yup

I hope you could help me with this part, so I have no problem with the stepper and no problem with the forms too when it comes to getting data input ​​and validating fields with yup .

but I have a problem with the checkboxes and autocomplete. when I go back to a previous step, I lose the values ​​I have already entered and validation no longer works with checkbox and autocomplete field.

**There is an example of a hook that I made for the checkboxes that I will use later in a form :**

```js
const CheckBoxField = (props) => {
  const { label, ...rest } = props;
  const [field, meta, helper] = useField(props);
  const { setValue } = helper;
  const [touched, error] = at(meta, "touched", "error");
  const isError = error && touched && true;
  function __renderHelperText() {
    if (isError) {
      return <FormHelperText>{error}</FormHelperText>;
    }
  }
  function _onChange(event) {
    setValue(event.target.checked);
  }

  const configFormControl = {
    ...field,
    ...rest,
    onChange: _onChange,
  };
  return (
    <FormControl
      component="fieldset"
      {...configFormControl}
      error={Boolean(isError)}
    >
      <FormControlLabel
        // value={field.checked}
        checked={field.checked}
        label={label}
        onChange={_onChange}
        control={
          <BpCheckbox
            {...configFormControl}
            // checked={field.checked}
            color="primary"
          />
        }
        color="primary"
      />
      {__renderHelperText()}
    </FormControl>
  );
};
```

**And there is the code for validation :**

```js
import * as yup from "yup";
 
import signUpFormModel from "../signUpFormModel";

const {
  formField: {
    terms //Boolean , used in checkboxes, should be true
  },
} = signUpFormModel;

const signUpValidationSchema = [
  yup.object().shape({
    [terms.name]: yup.boolean().oneOf([true], `${terms.requiredErrMsg}`), 
    //other fields ...
  }),
  //other forms ...
 
];

export default signUpValidationSchema;
```

**My Initial value :**

```js
import signUpFormModel from "../signUpFormModel";

const {
  formField: {
    terms,
  },
} = signUpFormModel;

const formInitialValue = {
  [terms.name]: false,
};

export default formInitialValue;
```

**and some props helper (used as model for my forms)**

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { Link } from "@mui/material";

const signUpFormModel = {
  formId: "registration",
  formField: {
 
    terms: {
      type: "checkbox",
      name: "terms",
      id: "terms",
      label: () => (
        <Fragment>
          J'accepte les{" "}
          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
            termes et conditions générales d'utilisation
          </Link>{" "}
          et la{" "}
          <Link href="#" variant="body2">
            politique de confidentialité
          </Link>
          .
        </Fragment>
      ),
      requiredErrMsg: "Vous devez accepter les termes et conditions",
    },
    
    
  },
};

export default signUpFormModel;
```

**Finaly the form itself :**

```js
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
import CheckBoxField from "../CheckBoxField";
 
 
const PrimarySignUpForm = (props) => {
  const {
    formField: {
      terms,
    },
  } = props;
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <CheckBoxField name={terms.name} label={terms.label()} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default PrimarySignUpForm;
```

**And this is how I made the stepper :**

```js
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import SignUpFormLogs from "../forms/SignUpFormLogs";
import { Formik, Form } from "formik";
import formInitialValuefrom from "../formModel/formInitialValue";
import signUpFormModel from "../formModel/signUpFormModel";
import signUpValidationSchema from "../formModel/signUpValidationSchema";
import {
  Button,
  Link,
  Step,
  StepLabel,
  Stepper,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
 


const steps = ["step1"];
const { formId, formField } = signUpFormModel;

function _renderSteps(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case "step1":
      return <SignUpFormLogs formField={formField} />;
    default:
      return <div>Not Found</div>;
  }
}

function _sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const SignUp = () => {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const currentValidationSchema = signUpValidationSchema[activeStep]; //activeStep
  const isLastStep = activeStep === steps.length - 1;

  async function _submitForm(values, actions) {
    await _sleep(1000);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
  }

  function _handleSubmit(values, actions) {
    if (isLastStep) {
      _submitForm(values, actions);
    } else {
      setActiveStep(activeStep + 1);
      actions.setTouched({});
      actions.setSubmitting(false);
    }
  }

  function _handleBack() {
    setActiveStep(activeStep - 1);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} sx={{ pt: 3, pb: 5 }}>
        {steps.map((label) => (
          <Step key={label}>
            <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>

      {activeStep === steps.length ? (
        <Typography variant="h6">Last step</Typography>
      ) : (
        <Formik
          initialValues={formInitialValuefrom}
          validationSchema={currentValidationSchema}
          onSubmit={_handleSubmit}
        >
          {({ isSubmitting }) => (
            <Form id={formId}>
              {_renderSteps(steps[activeStep])}

              {activeStep !== 0 && (
                <Button
                  onClick={_handleBack}
                  disabled={isSubmitting}
                  variant="outlined"
                  color="primary"
                  sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 2 }}
                >
                  Back
                </Button>
              )}

              <Button
                type="submit"
                disabled={isSubmitting}
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 2 }}
              >
                {isLastStep ? "Enregistrer" : "Suivant"}
              </Button>

              {isSubmitting && (
                <Typography variant="h6">submitting...</Typography>
              )}
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```